# HTTP Get Not Working

Tags: java, android, http-get

**Edit: I'm extremely sorry for how poorly I asked my question at first, I was extremely frustrated and tired but I know that really isn't an excuse. Anyway, I edited it. I have also already looked a lot on the StackOverflow forums and other ones and tried the methods on their, without result so I guess this isn't really a duplicate question.**

After hours of trying and using several methods I finally gave up and decided to post the question here. So frustrating that I can't get this to work, it's for a home automation project and learning new languages like C and python was never a problem while working on this project so not getting this to work is extremely frustrating. Anyway here is the code:

```
public void buttonOnClick(View v) {
    Button button = (Button) v;
    ((Button) v).setText("clicked");
        // The request here
        // The request here
        // The request here
        // The request here

        }
```

This is a simple application with one button that should send a simple http get request to 192.168.0.150/main_light/switch. I know this is supposed to work since I've always used HTTP GETs in Tasker for this (and it works in Python). I really hope someone can help me out here, thank you!

P.S. I know there are stil useless actions in here, I'm a JAVA Noob and decided just to not mess with anything until I can finally get this working.

Comment: Instead of posting a lot of irrelevant code that has nothing to do with firing the HTTP GET request, you should rather show what code you have tried in order to fire the request.

Comment: Try the answer from here [make an http request with android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505930/make-an-http-request-with-android)

Comment: @JanusVarmarken I'm extremely sorry, I have edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `HttpURLConnection` to achieve the same:

```
String serverURL = "http://192.168.0.150/main_light/switch";
URL url = new URL(serverURL);
HttpURLConnection connection = null;
try {
    connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    //Do something with this InputStream
    // handle the response
    int status = connection.getResponseCode();
    // If response is not success
    if (status != 200) {
        throw new IOException("Post failed with error code " + status);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e(TAG,e.toString());
} finally {
     if(connection != null)
         connection.disconnect();
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Of course this will not help as you are not reading the page that is sent by the server. So your code `gets` nothing.

Comment: Oops, missed out the most cruial thing. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Your code still does not retrieve the page.

Comment: I get an ANDROID.OS.NETWORKONMAINTHREADEXCPETION which probably means I should run it as an assync task I guess?

Comment: I got it to work using an async task, really stupid that I didn't think of it before since I had already tried this exact method. Anyway, thanks a lot answering my question considering how poorly it was asked. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Try using http://square.github.io/okhttp/

Put the code here like this:

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
           String run(String url) throws IOException {
           Request request = new Request.Builder()
               .url(url)
               .build();

           Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
           return response.body().string();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this method:

```
public static int get(String url) throws Exception {
    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");
    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        //consume response if any;
    }
    in.close();
    return responseCode;
}
```

Implement the consumption of the request if you need to.